# Text not displaying in Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter, display

I have the following code, and the error is that 1 positional argument (text) is missing. As far as I can see, I have included all arguments. Can anyone shed any light on this?

**Error**

```
TypeError: draw_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

**Code in question**

```
while 1:
        if ball1.hit_bottom ==False: #this creates a condition - inside the loop it continues to check to see if the ball has hit (or not) the bottom of the screen
            tk.update()
            ball1.draw()
            bat1.draw()
        else:
            draw1=Game()
            draw1.draw_text(300,200,'Goodbye')

        time.sleep(0.02) 
main()
```

**Class in which draw_text is defined.**

```
class Game:
    def game_loop(self,canvas):
        if hit_bottom==True:
            self.draw_text(300,200,'You Lose')
    def draw_text(self,canvas,x,y,text,size='40'):
        font=('Helvetica',size)
        return self.canvas.create_text(x,y,text=text,font=font)
```

New to Tkinter and after having done a lot of research, I still can't find specifics on getting this to work.

I also tried this:

```
  while 1:
        if ball1.hit_bottom ==False: #this creates a condition - inside the loop it continues to check to see if the ball has hit (or not) the bottom of the screen
            tk.update()
            ball1.draw()
            bat1.draw()
        else:
            game_over()

        time.sleep(0.02) 
main()
```

...with the following in the Ball class

```
  def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y) 
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id) 
        if pos[1] <=0: 
            self.y=6
            #we make a change here as well -alter the if statement to see if the ball has hit the bottom (equal or greater than canvas height), if so hit_bottom =True (as there is no more need to bounce the ball if the game is over!)
        if pos[3] >=self.canvas_height: 
            self.hit_bottom = True
            game_over()
```

this doesn't work either:

**Error:** 
Canvas is not defined

**Runnable example (whole code)**

```
from tkinter import *

import random
import time

class Game:
    def game_loop(self,canvas):
        if hit_bottom==True:
            self.draw_text(300,200,'You Lose')
    def draw_text(self,canvas,x,y,text,size='40'):
        font=('Helvetica',size)
        return self.canvas.create_text(x,y,text=text,font=font)

class Ball: 
    def __init__(self,canvas,bat,color):  
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.bat=bat 
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(30,30,50,50,fill=color) 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,100,200)
        starting_position=[-3,-2,-1,1,2,3] 
        random.shuffle(starting_position) 
        self.x = starting_position[0] 
        self.y = -3 
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
        #Add a hit_bottom object variable here..
        self.hit_bottom=False #...note we change the main loop at the bottom to include an if function that utilises this hit_bottom object variable


    def hit_bat(self,pos):
        bat_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.bat.id) 
        if pos[2] >=bat_pos[0] and pos[0] <=bat_pos[2]: 
            if pos[3]>=bat_pos[1] and pos[3] <= bat_pos[3]: 
                return True
        return False

    def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y) 
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id) 
        if pos[1] <=0: 
            self.y=6
            #we make a change here as well -alter the if statement to see if the ball has hit the bottom (equal or greater than canvas height), if so hit_bottom =True (as there is no more need to bounce the ball if the game is over!)
        if pos[3] >=self.canvas_height: 
            self.hit_bottom = True


        if self.hit_bat(pos) ==True: 
            self.y=-6 
        if pos[0] <=0:
            self.x=6
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=-6



class Pongbat():
    def __init__(self,canvas,color): 
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.id=canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,10,fill=color) 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,200,300)
        self.x=0
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width() 
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.left_turn)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>',self.right_turn)


    def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,0)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0]<=0: 
            self.x=0
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=0

    def left_turn(self,evt):
        self.x=-10 

    def right_turn(self,evt):
        self.x=10

def main():
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title("My 21st Century Pong Game")
    tk.resizable(0,0)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
    canvas=Canvas(tk,bg="white",width=500,height=400,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    bat1=Pongbat(canvas,'red') 
    ball1=Ball(canvas,bat1, 'green') 

    while 1:
        if ball1.hit_bottom ==False: #this creates a condition - inside the loop it continues to check to see if the ball has hit (or not) the bottom of the screen
            tk.update()
            ball1.draw()
            bat1.draw()
        else:
            draw1=Game()
            draw1.draw_text(300,200,'Goodbye')

        time.sleep(0.02) 
main()
```

Final update:

The latest thing I've tried is to add an **init** method as follows:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self,canvas):
     self.canvas=canvas

    def game_loop(self,canvas):
        if hit_bottom==True:
            self.draw_text(300,200,'You Lose')
    def draw_text(self,canvas,x,y,text,size='40'):
        font=('Helvetica',size)
        return self.canvas.create_text(x,y,text=text,font=font)
```

**and**

```
 while 1:
        if ball1.hit_bottom ==False: #this creates a condition - inside the loop it continues to check to see if the ball has hit (or not) the bottom of the screen
            tk.update()
            ball1.draw()
            bat1.draw()
        else:
            draw1=Game(canvas)
            #def draw_text(self,canvas,x,y,text,size='40'):
            draw1.draw_text(canvas,300,200,'Goodbye')

        time.sleep(0.02) 
main()
```

Now, the first error (about no canvas or no position argument) is gone, but the screen just hangs.

Comment: I've tried that: game_over(canvas)   ..and def game_over(canvas):  ..but it still doesn't work. Are you able to post as an answer

Comment: You have `canvas` as an argument in `draw_text`, and then never pass it. This means that 300 -> canvas, 200 -> x, 'Goodbye' -> y, so you therefore do not pass anything to `text`, and receive this error.

Comment: Thanks SneakyTurtle and abccd - just posting whole code

Comment: SneakyTurtle - are you able to post an answer, I cannot see what you mean in that, I cannot see how to solve the problem. :=(

Comment: When I do pass it canvas, like so: draw1.draw_text(canvas,300,200,'Goodbye')       I get the error: AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'canvas'   If you can post an answer, that solves the problem and displays the text, I will happily upvote and accept the answer! As you can see I HAVE tried various things, and am hoping someone on SO will stop me from going insane over this...!

Answer (score 1):

The screen hangs in your last update because the `while` loop is still running, you did not get/break out of it. You should `break` out of the while loop once your condition is met.

Here is your code with few other fixes:

Your `right_turn` and `left_turn` methods don't seem to work properly but I'll leave that for you to fix.

```
from tkinter import *

import random
import time

class Game:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas=canvas

    def game_loop(self): ##No need to pass canvas since you are using the same canvas in __init__
        if hit_bottom==True:
            self.draw_text(300,200,'You Lose')
    def draw_text(self, x, y, text, size='40'): ##No need to pass canvas
        font=('Helvetica',size)
        print "Ok"
        return self.canvas.create_text(x,y,text=text,font=font)

class Ball: 
    def __init__(self,canvas,bat,color):  
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.bat=bat 
        self.id=self.canvas.create_oval(30,30,50,50,fill=color) ## self.canvas
        self.canvas.move(self.id,100,200)
        starting_position=[-3,-2,-1,1,2,3] 
        random.shuffle(starting_position) 
        self.x = starting_position[0] 
        self.y = -3 
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
        #Add a hit_bottom object variable here..
        self.hit_bottom=False #...note we change the main loop at the bottom to include an if function that utilises this hit_bottom object variable


    def hit_bat(self,pos):
        bat_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.bat.id) 
        if pos[2] >=bat_pos[0] and pos[0] <=bat_pos[2]: 
            if pos[3]>=bat_pos[1] and pos[3] <= bat_pos[3]: 
                return True
        return False

    def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y) 
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id) 
        if pos[1] <=0: 
            self.y=6
            #we make a change here as well -alter the if statement to see if the ball has hit the bottom (equal or greater than canvas height), if so hit_bottom =True (as there is no more need to bounce the ball if the game is over!)
        if pos[3] >=self.canvas_height: 
            self.hit_bottom = True


        if self.hit_bat(pos) ==True: 
            self.y=-6 
        if pos[0] <=0:
            self.x=6
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=-6



class Pongbat():
    def __init__(self,canvas,color): 
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.id=self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,10,fill=color) ## self.canvas
        self.canvas.move(self.id,200,300)
        self.x=0
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width() 
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.left_turn)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>',self.right_turn)


    def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,0)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0]<=0: 
            self.x=0
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=0

    def left_turn(self,evt):
        self.x =-10 

    def right_turn(self,evt):
        self.x =+10

def main():
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title("My 21st Century Pong Game")
    tk.resizable(0,0)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
    canvas=Canvas(tk,bg="white",width=500,height=400,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    bat1=Pongbat(canvas,'red') 
    ball1=Ball(canvas,bat1, 'green') 

    while 1:
        if ball1.hit_bottom ==False: #this creates a condition - inside the loop it continues to check to see if the ball has hit (or not) the bottom of the screen
            tk.update()
            ball1.draw()
            bat1.draw()
        else:
            draw1=Game(canvas)
            #def draw_text(self,canvas,x,y,text,size='40'):
            draw1.draw_text(300,200,'Goodbye')
            break ## This stops the while loop

        time.sleep(0.02)
    tk.mainloop() # Keep the main window open
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

After making a number of changes, with most if not all of them indicated with comments, here's a runnable version of your script that will display the text at the end of the game.

```
from tkinter import *

import random
import time

class Game:
    def __init__(self, canvas): # Added method.
        self.canvas=canvas
    def game_loop(self):  # Removed canvas parameter.
        if hit_bottom==True:
            self.draw_text(self.canvas,300,200,'You Lose')  # Added self.canvas arg
    def draw_text(self,canvas,x,y,text,size='40'):
        font=('Helvetica',size)
        return self.canvas.create_text(x,y,text=text,font=font)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self,canvas,bat,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.bat=bat
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(30,30,50,50,fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,100,200)
        starting_position=[-3,-2,-1,1,2,3]
        random.shuffle(starting_position)
        self.x = starting_position[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
        #Add a hit_bottom object variable here..
        self.hit_bottom=False #...note we change the main loop at the bottom to include an if function that utilises this hit_bottom object variable


    def hit_bat(self,pos):
        bat_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.bat.id)
        if pos[2] >=bat_pos[0] and pos[0] <=bat_pos[2]:
            if pos[3]>=bat_pos[1] and pos[3] <= bat_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <=0:
            self.y=6
            #we make a change here as well -alter the if statement to see if the ball has hit the bottom (equal or greater than canvas height), if so hit_bottom =True (as there is no more need to bounce the ball if the game is over!)
        if pos[3] >=self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True


        if self.hit_bat(pos) ==True:
            self.y=-6
        if pos[0] <=0:
            self.x=6
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=-6



class Pongbat():
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.id=canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,10,fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,200,300)
        self.x=0
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.left_turn)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>',self.right_turn)


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,0)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0]<=0:
            self.x=0
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=0

    def left_turn(self,evt):
        self.x=-10

    def right_turn(self,evt):
        self.x=10

def main():
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title("My 21st Century Pong Game")
    tk.resizable(0,0)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
    canvas=Canvas(tk,bg="white",width=500,height=400,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    bat1=Pongbat(canvas,'red')
    ball1=Ball(canvas,bat1, 'green')

    while 1:
        if ball1.hit_bottom ==False: #this creates a condition - inside the loop it continues to check to see if the ball has hit (or not) the bottom of the screen
            ball1.draw()
            bat1.draw()
            tk.update()  # Allow screen to be updated (moved here after draw calls).
        else:
            draw1=Game(canvas)  # Added argument for new __init__() method.
            draw1.draw_text(canvas,300,200,'Goodbye')  # Added canvas arg.
            tk.update()  # Allow screen to be updated.
            canvas.after(3000)  # Added. Pause for a few seconds.
            return  # Terminate.

#        time.sleep(0.02)  # Shouldn't call sleep() in tkinter app.
        canvas.after(2)  # Use universal 'after()` method instead. Time in millisecs.
main()
```